# Why converting Foo** → const Foo** is an error in C++, but only a warning in C?

Tags: c++, c, const-correctness

```
char const c = 'x';       /* 1 */
char *p1;                 /* 2 */
char const **p2 = &p1;    /* 3 */
*p2 = &c;                 /* 4 */
*p1 = 'X';                /* 5 */
```

**Line 3** is *[disallowed](http://www.c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)* in C and is *[invalid](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion)* in C++. However, one gets an **[error](https://godbolt.org/z/4fzsz4WMW)** in C++, but *only* a **[warning](https://godbolt.org/z/sTWoePoxE)** in C.
The question is - why *only* a warning?

Comment: Note that when C++ started, it included `const`.  C started without `const` and it was later added.  I suspect the _warning only_ is due to that evolution.

Comment: The standards only require "a diagnostic", which is satisfied by either a warning or an error, so it is the choice of the compiler authors which one to issue.  For gcc, I think chux is right that it was meant to keep older or more careless C code working, whereas C++ code had no excuse. Other compilers might be different.

Comment: Use compiler flag -Werror

Comment: Please note that if you want to add/remove `const` modifiers in C++, you can use `const_cast<T>(...)` conversion. If you change your line 3 to `char const **p2 = const_cast<const char**>(&p1);` it will work without an error

Comment: Traditionally, C compilers only issue warnings for any incompatible pointer assignments. `int* x = NULL; double* t = x;` is a warning in many implementations. It means nothing whatsoever. Use `-Werror` unless you have a specific reason not to.

Comment: This works : `char * const *p2 = &p1;    /* 3 */`

Answer (score 0):

Both C & C++ deal with statement 3 as that "Assigning `const char**` with `char**` discards the `const` qualifier"
The difference is; C++ is more strict than C and doesn't allow `const` qualifier discarding.
This is really convenient in C++ and does lead to no issues contrary to C.

Imagine the following code:

```
    char const c = 'x';
    char *p1 = &c;
    *p1 = 'A';

    printf("c address: 0x%X, p1 is pointing to: 0x%X\n", &c, p1);
    printf("%c\n", c);
    printf("%c\n", *p1);
```

This is a compilable C code. One would think that assigning a new value to `*p1` should not be possible as it points to a `const` variable.
Also one would think that if it did happen and we could change the value of what p is pointing at this will also change the value of `c`
But this is not the case!!

The above code surprisingly generates:

```
c address: 0xEF3E146B, p1 is pointing to: 0xEF3E146B
x
A
```

So allowing this const qualifier to be discarded does lead to undefined behavior (which means it's up to the compiler to decide what to do).
This is fixed in C++ to avoid such ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

C has much more relaxed pointer rules than C++. C++ enforces a lot more type safety than C. Some of this is up to compilers to decide only to warn in C.

One example to look at is malloc, where `char* str = malloc(50);` is perfectly fine C but must be `char* str = (char*) malloc(50);` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: because they are different languages and have different rules. There is no C/C++ language.

Comment: This is only a half truth. C++ was intentionally designed to include C as a subset, and apart from rejected later C developments (VLA) and subtle semantic differences between later parallel developments (volatile?), C++ still effectively *contains* mainstream C. This conscious decision has made it a worse language than it could have been, so it was no accident and was made accepting a cost. What this question is asking is *why* Stroustrup decided to deviate from the otherwise governing C compatibility in this case. (And the answer is probably a stronger general emphasis on types in C++.)